# Error en el Box-Sizing

Tags: css3

Acabo de colocar la propiedad box-sizing con el valor border-box, mi duda es ¿por qué me aparece otra medida diferente en el inspector? Le he puesto un width de 140 px y un height de 140px a un div, pero al ver el inspector están otras medidas. Seleccione mi elemento con el inspector y ahí si me pone 140px.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `box-sizing: border-box;` incluye el valor del border, padding y margin dentro del da la caja padre. En este caso especificas el alto y ancho en `140px`. Siendo así el inspector de google chrome muestra los siguientes valores:

```
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
border-left: 5px;
border-right: 5px;
```

haciendo un total de `40px` de padding por los lados y `10px` de border por los lados aprovechando `50px` de tu contenedor, dejando así solo `90px` para tu contenido en total usas los `140px`.

Comment: Gracias, me olvide sumar los otros lados :)